# Whats the difference between bode plot linear and cartesian?

Tags: filter, ltspice, bode-plot

As in title, Whats the difference between bode plot linear and cartesian in LTspice? In both cases i get V(f) but the values differ. Which plot will give me values of voltage at given frequency that will actually appear if i measure it with multimeter?

[image: Bode]

[image: cartesian]

:EDIT

Thanks for the responses. The final answer is:
Bode gives us [voltage]*e^(-i[angle]) while cartesian 
gives sqrt[(Re)^2+(Im)^2].
Answering my question, voltage that will appear on the multimeter can be directly taken from [voltage] of bode plot

Comment: I think the better question to ask is: What's the difference between Cartesian and Bode Plots? Perhaps this is what you meant? Linear bode plotting has to do with how you want to scale your plot logarithmically.

Comment: Cartesian is giving the real component only (i.e not including the imaginary component). Bode is giving \$\sqrt{real^2 +imag^2}\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cartesian is, essentially, a Nyquist plot (i.e. a complex plane graph) but you've chosen to plot just the real component (x) against frequency (i.e not including the imaginary component).

Bode gives amplitude (\$\small \sqrt{real^2 +imag^2}\$) and phase angle. You've chosen to plot the amplitude against frequency, and not the phase